# How to Call Client-Side Code Before Server-Side Event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbEmployeeGroup" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
    AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged=" [Call java script to check first] then rbEmployeeGroup_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Employees" Value="employees"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Groups" Value="groups"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

How to call the javascript function before call rbEmployeeGroup_SelectedIndexChanged this code behind function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out. Just add the onClientClick = "..."

Answer (score 3):

You need to add an onclick handler to every radiobutton in your list.

This can be done in your server code before the control is rendered.

```
foreach (var item in rbEmployeeGroup.Items)
{
   item.Attributes.Add("onclick", "nameOfJavascriptFunction");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When we want to execute client code first than server code then we need to use Onclientclick . show below is one example:

```
<asp:Button 
    ID="btnAlelrt"
    runat="server"
    Text="SubmitDetails"
    OnClick="btnAlelrt_Click"
    OnClientClick="return confirm('Data Already Exists ,Do you Want Update?');"
/>
```